# Movie with dragon and thing that looks like Godzilla

Tags: story-identification, movie, dragons, godzilla

See this video:

In it, at 1:52, there is a clip of a movie with a dragon and a Godzilla-like (maybe Godzilla itself) creature. I have a crazy idea that it might be CGI. I know it’s a movie because of the aspect ratio. What is it?

The dragon:

[image: The dragon]

The thing that’s maybe Godzilla:

[image: The Godzilla-resembling monster]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's [*Godzilla* (2014)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godzilla_(2014_film)) and the other creature is a [MUTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUTO).

[image: Male MUTO bringing offering]

[This review](https://www.agonybooth.com/godzilla-2014-2-23349) has other images similar to the ones above:

[image: Godzilla breathing blue flame]